# Getting Guice CreationException when migrating from Play 2.5.3 to Play 2.6.6

Tags: java, dependency-injection, migration, guice, playframework-2.6

I've gone through the 2.6.x [Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26) and [WS Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/WSMigration26) and have worked through most of the initial errors, but I can't seem to get through this one that occurs on Application startup:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors: 
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientConfig. 
Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private. 
at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientConfig.class(AhcConfig.scala:37) while locating play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientConfig for the 1st parameter of play.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSAPI.<init>(AhcWSAPI.java:28) 
at play.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSModule.bindings(AhcWSModule.java:23): Binding(interface play.libs.ws.WSAPI to ConstructionTarget(class play.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSAPI)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
```

The WS Migration guide mentions that WSAPI is deprecated but it appears that GUICE is still trying to bind to the implemented class? I'm really not sure.

Please see my libraryDependencies if that helps.

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.1.0.Final",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1208.jre7",
  "com.elemica" %% "apollo-commons" % "0.1.47-SNAPSHOT",
  "com.jayway.jsonpath" % "json-path" % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0-M1",
  "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.6.2",
  "org.freemarker" % "freemarker" % "2.3.25-incubating",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.133",
  "org.redisson" % "redisson" % "2.1.4",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.196",
  ws,
  guice,
  openId
)
```

plugins.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.6")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.11")
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.2.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably being caused by some dependency hell. Since you are adding `play-mailer` `5.0.0-M1`, which is not a final version but a milestone (where APIs are still unstable), I suspect that is the cause of the problem.

Try with the following version of play-mailer:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! You're definitely correct about the dependency hell scenario, and this was a good lead. Unfortunately it still hasn't solved my issue. My next approach will be starting with a fresh 2.6.6 play application and try to approach it from that angle.

Comment: You should post your plugins.sbt too.

Comment: Done; I've noticed that updating the mailer actually causes an additional CreationException (as well as the existing one) so my dependency game is certainly in trouble.

Comment: Yeah. I would recommend that you update pkay-enhancer and sbt-web plugins too (although pkay-enhancer is more a suspect here). If possible, use SBT-dependency-graph to check if there is a older version of play being added to your project.

Answer (score 1):

marcospereira's answer was certianly on the right path! It was dependency conflict issue. I noticed the class it was complaining about is actually on an old library (play.libs.ws.WSAPI) but wasn't sure how that dependency was getting added to my project.

With the help of [this amazing plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph/) I finally saw that:

`"com.elemica" %% "apollo-commons" % "0.1.47-SNAPSHOT"` was pulling in the old **play-java-ws_2.11** library and causing the issue.

I moved that dependency down the chain and that seemed to fix it, but since the order can't be guaranteed (as marco mentions below) I updated the apollo-commons project to use play 2.6.6 as well and now the outdated class files are no longer getting referenced.

Comment: What do you mean by "moved the dependency down the chain"? If by that you mean you just moved the line down in the file, this is not the right solution since there are no guarantees the classpath order will be preserved when deploying/testing etc. Better possible solutions are either release a `apollo-commons` version which depends on Play 2.6 instead or [exclude the transitive dependency](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies).

Comment: You're right, moving it down was simply verifying / proving that it was indeed a dependency conflict issue (at least in my mind). The permanant/correct solution was exactly as you said and since we have the ability to update that jar with an updated version of play, that's what I did. I've updated the answer.